# Determine if users Locale is day-month-year or month-day-year

Tags: java, internationalization, simpledateformat, date-formatting, java-time

Unlike the rest of the world who use day-month-year, [the US uses month-day-year formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States#Date).

I would like to programatically determine whether the user uses day-month or month-day.

I am able to do this with the following, but I am unsure if there is an easier way?

```
String localisedDateFormat = ((SimpleDateFormat) SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance()).toPattern().toLowerCase();

boolean usFormat = localisedDateFormat.indexOf('d') > localisedDateFormat.indexOf('m');
```

I do not think this is possible with a `DateTimeFormatter` as you cannot get the underlying `pattern`.

Comment: `MDY` format is not uniquely American - [several other countries use it as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), although it *is* much less common than `DMY` format

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  To construct a UI with separate input fields for the date parts?

Comment: @JonK this nuance is exactly why I wanted to get this based off the Locale instead.

Comment: @VGR parsing data from files. I have a predefined set of date formats the application uses, but depending on the locale they can either be in (for example) dd/MM/yy or MM/dd/yy. I use the locale to modify the formats appropriately.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale)` or `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale)`?

Comment: @VGR those were representative examples. Lets say the format is some other format like ddMMyyyy vs MMddyyyy- the format in the data is out of my control, but using the Locale can guide me to create a date format.

Comment: I guess you can't infer the locale (or the format) with just the string. What about 01022019, is it Jan 2nd or Feb 1st?

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis no, but I can infer the locale of the data from the user. I am aware of the limitations of this.

Comment: You can get the pattern from `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern`. Much recommended over the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @Jakg if you have the user's locale and you can safely assume it's the locale of his input (I would do so) you should definitely base your decision on it

Comment: `localisedDateFormat.indexOf('m')` doesn’t give you what you want. Format pattern letters are case sensitive! ALso you should check for `-1` just in case that the letter isn’t there.

Comment: @OleV.V. I lower-cased the format first. You are correct on the -1.

Comment: Sorry, missed the lower-casing. I wouldn’t do that myself, just in case (no pun intended).

Comment: *"Unlike the rest of the world who use day-month-year"* A lot of places uses YMD format, e.g. Canada, China, Japan, South Africa, ...

Comment: You can't really split locales in `MDY` / `DMY` / `YMD` "buckets", because the order might depend on the date format (short / medium / long full). For example in en-CA uses 'June 25, 2010' (MDY) for long format but '2010-06-25' (YMD) for short format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;DR:* Call this helper method, which returns `YMD`, `DMY`, or `MDY`.

```
public static String getDateFieldOrder(Locale locale) {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale));
    return fmt.toPattern().replaceAll("[^yMd]|(?<=(.))\\1", "").toUpperCase();
}
```

---

To get the field order, ask for a `DateFormat`, and analyze the pattern used to build it:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale));
String pattern = fmt.toPattern();
```

This will give you patterns like this:

```
dd.MM.yy
M/d/yy
y-MM-dd
d. M. y
```

So, remove non-letters and repeating letters:

```
pattern = pattern.replaceAll("\\P{L}", "").replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

To see the potential results, you can run this code (Java 5+):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>();
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale));
    String pattern = fmt.toPattern().replaceAll("\\P{L}", "").replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
    Set<String> set = map.get(pattern);
    if (set == null)
        map.put(pattern, set = new TreeSet<String>());
    set.add(locale.getDisplayName(Locale.US));
}
for (Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
```

*Sample Output (Java 11)*

```
GyMd = [Japanese (Japan, JP, Japanese Calendar)]
Mdy = [Bodo, Bodo (India), Cherokee, Cherokee (United States), English, English (American Samoa), English (Burundi), English (Guam), English (Marshall Islands), English (Northern Mariana Islands), English (Puerto Rico), English (U.S. Outlying Islands), English (U.S. Virgin Islands), English (United States), English (United States, Computer), Ewe, Ewe (Ghana), Ewe (Togo), Filipino, Filipino (Philippines), Kashmiri, Kashmiri (India), Odia, Odia (India), Spanish (Panama), Spanish (Puerto Rico), Zulu, Zulu (South Africa)]
dMy = [Aghem, Aghem (Cameroon), Albanian, Albanian (Albania), Albanian (Kosovo), Albanian (Macedonia), Amharic, Amharic (Ethiopia), Arabic, Arabic (Algeria), Arabic (Bahrain), Arabic (Chad), Arabic (Comoros), Arabic (Djibouti), Arabic (Egypt), Arabic (Eritrea), Arabic (Iraq), Arabic (Israel), Arabic (Jordan), Arabic (Kuwait), Arabic (Lebanon), Arabic (Libya), Arabic (Mauritania), Arabic (Morocco), Arabic (Oman), Arabic (Palestinian Territories), Arabic (Qatar), Arabic (Saudi Arabia), Arabic (Somalia), Arabic (South Sudan), Arabic (Sudan), Arabic (Syria), Arabic (Tunisia), Arabic (United Arab Emirates), Arabic (Western Sahara), Arabic (World), Arabic (Yemen), Armenian, Armenian (Armenia), Assamese, Assamese (India), Asturian, Asturian (Spain), Asu, Asu (Tanzania), Azerbaijani, Azerbaijani (Cyrillic), Azerbaijani (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan), Azerbaijani (Latin), Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan), Bafia, Bafia (Cameroon), Bambara, Bambara (Mali), Bangla, Bangla (Bangladesh), Bangla (India), Basaa, Basaa (Cameroon), Belarusian, Belarusian (Belarus), Bemba, Bemba (Zambia), Bena, Bena (Tanzania), Bosnian, Bosnian (Cyrillic), Bosnian (Cyrillic, Bosnia & Herzegovina), Bosnian (Latin), Bosnian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina), Breton, Breton (France), Burmese, Burmese (Myanmar (Burma)), Catalan, Catalan (Andorra), Catalan (France), Catalan (Italy), Catalan (Spain), Catalan (Spain, Valencian), Central Atlas Tamazight, Central Atlas Tamazight (Morocco), Chakma, Chakma (Bangladesh), Chakma (India), Chiga, Chiga (Uganda), Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China), Chinese (Simplified, Hong Kong SAR China), Chinese (Simplified, Macau SAR China), Chinese (Simplified, Singapore), Chinese (Singapore), Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong SAR China), Chinese (Traditional, Macau SAR China), Colognian, Colognian (Germany), Croatian, Croatian (Bosnia & Herzegovina), Croatian (Croatia), Czech, Czech (Czechia), Danish, Danish (Denmark), Danish (Greenland), Duala, Duala (Cameroon), Dutch, Dutch (Aruba), Dutch (Belgium), Dutch (Caribbean Netherlands), Dutch (Curaçao), Dutch (Netherlands), Dutch (Sint Maarten), Dutch (Suriname), Embu, Embu (Kenya), English (Anguilla), English (Antigua & Barbuda), English (Australia), English (Austria), English (Bahamas), English (Barbados), English (Belgium), English (Belize), English (Bermuda), English (Botswana), English (British Indian Ocean Territory), English (British Virgin Islands), English (Cameroon), English (Cayman Islands), English (Christmas Island), English (Cocos (Keeling) Islands), English (Cook Islands), English (Cyprus), English (Denmark), English (Diego Garcia), English (Dominica), English (Eritrea), English (Europe), English (Falkland Islands), English (Fiji), English (Finland), English (Gambia), English (Germany), English (Ghana), English (Gibraltar), English (Grenada), English (Guernsey), English (Guyana), English (Hong Kong SAR China), English (India), English (Ireland), English (Isle of Man), English (Israel), English (Jamaica), English (Jersey), English (Kenya), English (Kiribati), English (Lesotho), English (Liberia), English (Macau SAR China), English (Madagascar), English (Malawi), English (Malaysia), English (Malta), English (Mauritius), English (Micronesia), English (Montserrat), English (Namibia), English (Nauru), English (Netherlands), English (New Zealand), English (Nigeria), English (Niue), English (Norfolk Island), English (Pakistan), English (Palau), English (Papua New Guinea), English (Philippines), English (Pitcairn Islands), English (Rwanda), English (Samoa), English (Seychelles), English (Sierra Leone), English (Singapore), English (Sint Maarten), English (Slovenia), English (Solomon Islands), English (South Sudan), English (St. Helena), English (St. Kitts & Nevis), English (St. Lucia), English (St. Vincent & Grenadines), English (Sudan), English (Swaziland), English (Switzerland), English (Tanzania), English (Tokelau), English (Tonga), English (Trinidad & Tobago), English (Turks & Caicos Islands), English (Tuvalu), English (Uganda), English (United Kingdom), English (Vanuatu), English (World), English (Zambia), English (Zimbabwe), Estonian, Estonian (Estonia), Ewondo, Ewondo (Cameroon), Faroese, Faroese (Denmark), Faroese (Faroe Islands), Finnish, Finnish (Finland), French, French (Algeria), French (Belgium), French (Benin), French (Burkina Faso), French (Burundi), French (Cameroon), French (Central African Republic), French (Chad), French (Comoros), French (Congo - Brazzaville), French (Congo - Kinshasa), French (Côte d’Ivoire), French (Djibouti), French (Equatorial Guinea), French (France), French (French Guiana), French (French Polynesia), French (Gabon), French (Guadeloupe), French (Guinea), French (Haiti), French (Luxembourg), French (Madagascar), French (Mali), French (Martinique), French (Mauritania), French (Mauritius), French (Mayotte), French (Monaco), French (Morocco), French (New Caledonia), French (Niger), French (Rwanda), French (Réunion), French (Senegal), French (Seychelles), French (St. Barthélemy), French (St. Martin), French (St. Pierre & Miquelon), French (Switzerland), French (Syria), French (Togo), French (Tunisia), French (Vanuatu), French (Wallis & Futuna), Friulian, Friulian (Italy), Fulah, Fulah (Cameroon), Fulah (Guinea), Fulah (Mauritania), Fulah (Senegal), Galician, Galician (Spain), Ganda, Ganda (Uganda), Georgian, Georgian (Georgia), German, German (Austria), German (Belgium), German (Germany), German (Italy), German (Liechtenstein), German (Luxembourg), German (Switzerland), Greek, Greek (Cyprus), Greek (Greece), Gujarati, Gujarati (India), Gusii, Gusii (Kenya), Hausa, Hausa (Ghana), Hausa (Niger), Hausa (Nigeria), Hawaiian, Hawaiian (United States), Hebrew, Hebrew (Israel), Hindi, Hindi (India), Icelandic, Icelandic (Iceland), Igbo, Igbo (Nigeria), Inari Sami, Inari Sami (Finland), Indonesian, Indonesian (Indonesia), Irish, Irish (Ireland), Italian, Italian (Italy), Italian (San Marino), Italian (Switzerland), Italian (Vatican City), Jola-Fonyi, Jola-Fonyi (Senegal), Kabuverdianu, Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde), Kabyle, Kabyle (Algeria), Kako, Kako (Cameroon), Kalenjin, Kalenjin (Kenya), Kamba, Kamba (Kenya), Kannada, Kannada (India), Kazakh, Kazakh (Kazakhstan), Khmer, Khmer (Cambodia), Kikuyu, Kikuyu (Kenya), Konkani, Konkani (India), Koyra Chiini, Koyra Chiini (Mali), Koyraboro Senni, Koyraboro Senni (Mali), Kwasio, Kwasio (Cameroon), Kyrgyz, Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan), Langi, Langi (Tanzania), Lao, Lao (Laos), Latvian, Latvian (Latvia), Lingala, Lingala (Angola), Lingala (Central African Republic), Lingala (Congo - Brazzaville), Lingala (Congo - Kinshasa), Lower Sorbian, Lower Sorbian (Germany), Luba-Katanga, Luba-Katanga (Congo - Kinshasa), Luo, Luo (Kenya), Luxembourgish, Luxembourgish (Luxembourg), Luyia, Luyia (Kenya), Macedonian, Macedonian (Macedonia), Machame, Machame (Tanzania), Makhuwa-Meetto, Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique), Makonde, Makonde (Tanzania), Malay, Malay (Brunei), Malay (Malaysia), Malay (Singapore), Malayalam, Malayalam (India), Maltese, Maltese (Malta), Marathi, Marathi (India), Masai, Masai (Kenya), Masai (Tanzania), Meru, Meru (Kenya), Morisyen, Morisyen (Mauritius), Mundang, Mundang (Cameroon), Nama, Nama (Namibia), Ngiemboon, Ngiemboon (Cameroon), North Ndebele, North Ndebele (Zimbabwe), Northern Sami (Finland), Norwegian, Norwegian (Norway), Norwegian (Norway, Nynorsk), Norwegian Bokmål, Norwegian Bokmål (Norway), Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard & Jan Mayen), Norwegian Nynorsk, Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway), Nuer, Nuer (South Sudan), Nyankole, Nyankole (Uganda), Oromo, Oromo (Ethiopia), Oromo (Kenya), Ossetic, Ossetic (Georgia), Ossetic (Russia), Polish, Polish (Poland), Portuguese, Portuguese (Angola), Portuguese (Brazil), Portuguese (Cape Verde), Portuguese (Equatorial Guinea), Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau), Portuguese (Luxembourg), Portuguese (Macau SAR China), Portuguese (Mozambique), Portuguese (Portugal), Portuguese (Switzerland), Portuguese (São Tomé & Príncipe), Portuguese (Timor-Leste), Punjabi, Punjabi (Arabic), Punjabi (Arabic, Pakistan), Punjabi (Gurmukhi), Punjabi (Gurmukhi, India), Quechua, Quechua (Bolivia), Quechua (Ecuador), Quechua (Peru), Romanian, Romanian (Moldova), Romanian (Romania), Romansh, Romansh (Switzerland), Rombo, Rombo (Tanzania), Rundi, Rundi (Burundi), Russian, Russian (Belarus), Russian (Kazakhstan), Russian (Kyrgyzstan), Russian (Moldova), Russian (Russia), Russian (Ukraine), Rwa, Rwa (Tanzania), Samburu, Samburu (Kenya), Sango, Sango (Central African Republic), Sangu, Sangu (Tanzania), Scottish Gaelic, Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom), Sena, Sena (Mozambique), Serbian, Serbian (Bosnia & Herzegovina), Serbian (Cyrillic), Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia & Herzegovina), Serbian (Cyrillic, Kosovo), Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro), Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia), Serbian (Latin), Serbian (Latin, Bosnia & Herzegovina), Serbian (Latin, Kosovo), Serbian (Latin, Montenegro), Serbian (Latin, Serbia), Serbian (Montenegro), Serbian (Serbia and Montenegro), Serbian (Serbia), Shambala, Shambala (Tanzania), Slovak, Slovak (Slovakia), Slovenian, Slovenian (Slovenia), Soga, Soga (Uganda), Somali, Somali (Djibouti), Somali (Ethiopia), Somali (Kenya), Somali (Somalia), Spanish, Spanish (Argentina), Spanish (Belize), Spanish (Bolivia), Spanish (Brazil), Spanish (Canary Islands), Spanish (Ceuta & Melilla), Spanish (Chile), Spanish (Colombia), Spanish (Costa Rica), Spanish (Cuba), Spanish (Dominican Republic), Spanish (Ecuador), Spanish (El Salvador), Spanish (Equatorial Guinea), Spanish (Guatemala), Spanish (Honduras), Spanish (Latin America), Spanish (Mexico), Spanish (Nicaragua), Spanish (Paraguay), Spanish (Peru), Spanish (Philippines), Spanish (Spain), Spanish (United States), Spanish (Uruguay), Spanish (Venezuela), Standard Moroccan Tamazight, Standard Moroccan Tamazight (Morocco), Swahili, Swahili (Congo - Kinshasa), Swahili (Kenya), Swahili (Tanzania), Swahili (Uganda), Swedish (Finland), Swiss German, Swiss German (France), Swiss German (Liechtenstein), Swiss German (Switzerland), Tachelhit, Tachelhit (Latin), Tachelhit (Latin, Morocco), Tachelhit (Tifinagh), Tachelhit (Tifinagh, Morocco), Taita, Taita (Kenya), Tajik, Tajik (Tajikistan), Tamil, Tamil (India), Tamil (Malaysia), Tamil (Singapore), Tamil (Sri Lanka), Tasawaq, Tasawaq (Niger), Tatar, Tatar (Russia), Telugu, Telugu (India), Teso, Teso (Kenya), Teso (Uganda), Thai, Thai (Thailand), Thai (Thailand, TH, Thai Digits), Tigrinya, Tigrinya (Eritrea), Tigrinya (Ethiopia), Tongan, Tongan (Tonga), Turkish, Turkish (Cyprus), Turkish (Turkey), Turkmen, Turkmen (Turkmenistan), Ukrainian, Ukrainian (Ukraine), Upper Sorbian, Upper Sorbian (Germany), Urdu, Urdu (India), Urdu (Pakistan), Uzbek, Uzbek (Cyrillic), Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan), Uzbek (Latin), Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan), Vai, Vai (Latin), Vai (Latin, Liberia), Vai (Vai), Vai (Vai, Liberia), Vietnamese, Vietnamese (Vietnam), Vunjo, Vunjo (Tanzania), Welsh, Welsh (United Kingdom), Western Frisian, Western Frisian (Netherlands), Wolof, Wolof (Senegal), Yangben, Yangben (Cameroon), Yiddish, Yiddish (World), Yoruba, Yoruba (Benin), Yoruba (Nigeria), Zarma, Zarma (Niger)]
dMyг = [Bulgarian, Bulgarian (Bulgaria)]
yMd = [, Afrikaans, Afrikaans (Namibia), Afrikaans (South Africa), Akan, Akan (Ghana), Basque, Basque (Spain), Cantonese, Cantonese (Simplified), Cantonese (Simplified, China), Cantonese (Traditional), Cantonese (Traditional, Hong Kong SAR China), Central Kurdish, Central Kurdish (Iran), Central Kurdish (Iraq), Chechen, Chechen (Russia), Chinese, Chinese (China), Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Simplified, China), Chinese (Taiwan), Chinese (Traditional), Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan), Church Slavic, Church Slavic (Russia), Cornish, Cornish (United Kingdom), Dzongkha, Dzongkha (Bhutan), English (Canada), English (South Africa), English (Sweden), Esperanto, Esperanto (World), French (Canada), Hungarian, Hungarian (Hungary), Japanese, Japanese (Japan), Kalaallisut, Kalaallisut (Greenland), Kinyarwanda, Kinyarwanda (Rwanda), Korean, Korean (North Korea), Korean (South Korea), Lakota, Lakota (United States), Lithuanian, Lithuanian (Lithuania), Low German, Low German (Germany), Low German (Netherlands), Malagasy, Malagasy (Madagascar), Manx, Manx (Isle of Man), Mazanderani, Mazanderani (Iran), Metaʼ, Metaʼ (Cameroon), Mongolian, Mongolian (Mongolia), Nepali, Nepali (India), Nepali (Nepal), Ngomba, Ngomba (Cameroon), Northern Luri, Northern Luri (Iran), Northern Luri (Iraq), Northern Sami, Northern Sami (Norway), Northern Sami (Sweden), Pashto, Pashto (Afghanistan), Persian, Persian (Afghanistan), Persian (Iran), Prussian, Prussian (World), Sakha, Sakha (Russia), Shona, Shona (Zimbabwe), Sichuan Yi, Sichuan Yi (China), Sindhi, Sindhi (Pakistan), Sinhala, Sinhala (Sri Lanka), Swedish, Swedish (Sweden), Swedish (Åland Islands), Tibetan, Tibetan (China), Tibetan (India), Uyghur, Uyghur (China), Uzbek (Arabic), Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan), Volapük, Volapük (World), Walser, Walser (Switzerland)]
```

If needed, you can eliminate the `G` and `r` pattern letters too. Instead of `replaceAll("\\P{L}", "")`, use `replaceAll("[^yMd]", "")`.

You can of course call `toUpperCase()` if you prefer values like `YMD`, `DMY` and `MDY`.

Comment: Nice thought out. Why show the young ones the use of the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class when `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern` can give you the same?

Comment: @OleV.V. Same reason I changed the test code from using streams to do it the old-fashioned way: To give a solution that anyone can use, even Android programmers and other poor people stuck on Java 7 or earlier. It's not like `SimpleDateFormat` is going away (hasn't even been deprecated yet), and for *this*, the problems with the old API is a non-issue.

Comment: Thanks! Used a modified version using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern` method discussed in the comments.

I like the idea much better of returning a descriptor rather than a simple boolean, especially now I know there's a third case I've not considered (`yMd`).

Comment: For anyone who’s curious (like me), the `r` in the Bulgarian formats is a literal (not a pattern letter). The format string is `d.MM.yy 'г'.`, so the date is formatted as `26.07.19 г.`. I don’t know what it means.

Comment: @OleV.V. According to [this page](https://blazingbulgaria.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/time-in-bulgarian/), it is the initial for the word година / year.